# If condition only verifies first statement

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to add users to my database table. Here is the method for the add button:

```
if (userDG.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.Equals(null) && 
    userDG.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.Equals(null))
    MessageBox.Show("Please select a function for the user");

if (userDG.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.Equals(true) && 
    userDG.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.Equals(true))
    MessageBox.Show("Choose either programmer or tester for a user");
else
    userTableAdapter1.Update(database1DataSet1.User);
```

The second `if` and the `else` work good. The first if only verifies the first statement. For this code above it will add the user anyway without displaying the message. I have also tried:

```
if (!(userDG.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.Equals(true)) && 
    !(userDG.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.Equals(true)))
```

For example:

- first column: `isprogrammer` (boolean)
- second: `istester` (boolean)

If `isprogrammer` is unchecked and `istester` is checked, the message is shown, which is wrong, because not both of them are unchecked.

If I check `isprogrammer` and leave `istester` unchecked it will add the user which is good.

Extra info: the 2 columns are of type `Boolean`. The first `if` is supposed to verify if both are unchecked and if they are the corresponding message is supposed to appear.

In my case: it adds the user even if both are unchecked.

Comment: Please show us what the exact values are (have you debugged it?).

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to make sure that's what happening?

Comment: If the first part of a boolean and statement evaluates to false, the second part is short-circuited (because there's no way that the statement could ever evaluate to true).

Comment: Is the problem that a user gets updated if both check boxes are unchecked? If so you should mention that in your question.

Comment: "The first if only verifies the first statement" What do you mean by this exactly? Which values for Cells[4] and Cells[3] give the wrong results?

Comment: Thanks for your update. Is the code you posted the complete code or did you omit any lines? If so, add braces around the code blocks inside the `if-else-if-else` to solve your problem. In any case it's good practice to do so.

Comment: the first column is "isProgrammer"and it is of type boolean. The second column is "isTester"and it is also of type boolean. If i leave both unchecked it displays the error but only because the isProgrammer value is unchecked. If I check the isTester and leave the isProgrammer  unchecked , again it will display the error. It should add the user. The problem is that this happens in this case:    if (!(userDG.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.Equals(true)) && !(userDG.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.Equals(true)))

Comment: In the first case ( if (userDG.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.Equals(false) && userDG.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.Equals(false)) ) it will add the user anyway when i leave both unchecked when it should display the message.

Comment: Could you use the debugger to check that checking and unchecking the boxes actually sets `userDG.CurrentRow.Cells[4]` and `userDG.CurrentRow.Cells[3]` to `true` and `false` as it should?

Comment: If you leave them unchecked is this returning you 'null' instead of 'false'?

Comment: Can you show a sample of the current row? You're sure the indexes you're using are referencing the right cells (index is zero based)?

Comment: @BenAaronson i used the debugger to check. it is returning null not false. I have tried with null instead of false before. Apparently the problem is that i used && instead of &. Thank you all for your replies!

Comment: @dsanatomy That's a strange fix to your problem. I suppose if all you care about is that it works somehow, that's fine, but generally the right solution is to make sure you get false when you want it. E.g. check the value and if it's null, manually set it to false.

Comment: @BenAaronson I didn't need to set it to false. It automatically set to NULL which is okay cause i only needed to do a constraint on my add method. I don't need its value to be false for anything, i just assumed it would be false if it wasn't true.

Comment: @sr28 apparently it did return null instead of false but even if i would have replaced it (which i did in my question) it wouldn't have made a different. the problem was that i used && instead of &. But the fact that you pointed that out helped me, thank you.

Comment: @dsanatomy `Equals(null)` [should always return false](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)! Something is quite iffy with your question, and this is partly due to your preconception that the issue has to be the `if` statement. To prevent this in your future questions: have a read about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Eric i'm not sure this applies here. I mean if the column allows nulls, i go into my database and see that a specific row has its isProgrammer column value NULL , why would it return false if i want to check if it's null? I mean, the code works now , with Equals(null) returning true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the first part of the `&&` expression in the `if` turns out to be false, the program already knows the `&&` expression is going to be false, too, so there's no need to check the second part. This is called "short-circuiting"

Try using a single `&` instead of two, then both sides of the expression are always evaluated.

Comment: This won't make a difference as the operands in the first `if` shouldn't have any side-effects.

Comment: this would only apply if the first operand evaluated to false.  Since it would need to evaluate to true in order to execute the message box, the second operand would still be evaluated. "short-circuiting" does not apply here.

Comment: "Since it evaluates to true [...]" how do you know this?

Comment: Second @Eric's remark. While I too at first thought that the (rather unclear) question was asking about how to avoid short-circuiting in conditional statements, after cleaning the question some it seems OP is experiencing other issues. (And it baffles me that changing `&&` to `&` "solved" the issue; I'd hazard a guess that it was a red herring and a simultaneous change (e.g. checking and then unchecking the boxes may've caused the cell to go from `NULL` to `false`) was in fact solving the issue.)

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to do:

```
if (userDG.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.Equals(false) && userDG.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.Equals(false))
  MessageBox.Show("Please select a function for the user");
else if (userDG.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.Equals(true) && userDG.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.Equals(true))
  MessageBox.Show("Choose either programmer or tester for a user");
else
  userTableAdapter1.Update(database1DataSet1.User);
```

If both `Cells[3].Value` and `Cells[4].Value` equals `false` your code will still enter the `else` case and update the user. This is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: while changing the `if` to `else if` may be good practice, I don't believe that would solve his problem.  The first `if` statement isn't working as the op expected.

Comment: No you see there is a big difference here. The `else` case will run if both values are `false` which is probably the cause of the problem. Though to the OP it seems that the cause is short circuit of the `if-statement`. I might be wrong though.

Comment: While I agree that this probably fixes a bug, I don't think it's the same issue that dsanatomy is asking about. Though it's difficult to tell because the wording of the question is quite unclear

Comment: @SaniHuttunen I have tried that before but it doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: @dsanatomy: Then what exactly is the problem? Not displaying the first `MessageBox`? The second `MessageBox`? Not updateing the user?

Comment: @SaniHuttunen if i leave both columns unchecked it adds the user anyway, when it should display the message.

Comment: As i said in the problem, the second if and else statements work good. The first IF is the problem.